# how to active serial ports on raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, embedded, raspbian

i have raspberry 3 model B 
i need to read RFID 125K with Serial Ports (TX , RX)
how can I setup the raspberry to read the sensor ?
 i have the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygame
import subprocess
import time
import serial
import random
import os
import urllib2
from pygame import display,movie
import thread
from subprocess import Popen
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
pygame.init()
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
threadRunning=False
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0")
ser.baudrate=9600
w=0
h=0
size=(w,h)
flag=0
#,pygame.FULLSCREEN

while True:    
    print('start reading')        
    global dta
    dta=ser.read(16)
    dta=dta.strip()
    print(dta)

    continue
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your listed program? You don't seem to ask a question.

Comment: Are you sure GPIO `serial` is `ttyAMA0`?